# Send email on status change

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, email, spring-mvc

I have a project which currently only does methods when I run the site. Now I need to implement a thread which checks the DB/the website for status-changes so I can send out a mail if something occurs. I have successfully added the functionality to mail someone, and also know the logic on how to do this. The problem occurs when I try to write the code, I don't know how to do it (Since I didn't know the back-end mostly, and now I have the responsibility for the project.

The logic would be to implement a java-thread (runnable) and then check the previous color with the new one and if it has changed send out an mail (The colors are statuses, for example, green & red). What is the most understandable and easy way to do this? I'll write the function names so you get an idea of what I have.

I have been stuck with this for a week and don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

The method in the class for the object that changes color:

```
    public void setColour(List<Status> statusar, List<Category> subcategories) {
    for (int index = 0; index < subcategories.size(); index++) {
        if (this.statusColor.compareToIgnoreCase("red") != 0) {

            if ((((Status)statusar.get(index)).getStatusColor().compareToIgnoreCase("green") == 0)
                    && (this.priority < ((Category)subcategories.get(index)).getPriority())) {
                this.statusColor = "GREEN";
                this.priority = ((Category)subcategories.get(index)).getPriority();
            }

            if (((((Status)statusar.get(index)).getStatusColor().compareToIgnoreCase("red") == 0)
                    && (((Category)subcategories.get(index)).getPriority() == 2))
                    || ((((Status)statusar.get(index)).getStatusColor().compareToIgnoreCase("yellow") == 0)
                    && (this.priority <= ((Category)subcategories.get(index)).getPriority()))
                    || ((((Status)statusar.get(index)).getStatusColor().compareToIgnoreCase("yellow") == 0)
                    && (((Category)subcategories.get(index)).getPriority() == 3))) {
                this.statusColor = "YELLOW";
                this.priority = ((Category)subcategories.get(index)).getPriority();
            }

            if (((((Status)statusar.get(index)).getStatusColor().compareToIgnoreCase("red") == 0)
                    && (((Category)subcategories.get(index)).getPriority() == 3))
                    || ((((Status)statusar.get(index)).getStatusColor().compareToIgnoreCase("red") == 0)
                    && (this.priority <= ((Category)subcategories.get(index)).getPriority()))) {
                this.statusColor = "RED";
                this.priority = ((Category)subcategories.get(index)).getPriority();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A color function I found in the DB part:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> listColorsOverDays(String days, String categoryName) {
    String SQL_getColors = "SELECT COUNT(*) count,color FROM ( ";
    SQL_getColors += " SELECT CASE";
    SQL_getColors += " WHEN CAST(status.value AS DECIMAL) >= CAST(greenFrom AS DECIMAL) AND CAST(status.value AS DECIMAL) <= CAST(greenTo AS DECIMAL) THEN 'GREEN' ";
    SQL_getColors += " WHEN CAST(status.value AS DECIMAL) >= CAST(yellowFrom AS DECIMAL) AND CAST(status.value AS DECIMAL) <= CAST(yellowTo AS DECIMAL) THEN 'YELLOW' ";
    SQL_getColors += " ELSE 'RED' END AS color ";
    SQL_getColors += " FROM status INNER JOIN category ON status.idCategory = category.idCategory ";
    SQL_getColors += " INNER JOIN threshold ON category.idCategory = threshold.idCategory ";
    SQL_getColors += " WHERE status.timeStamp>DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL " + days + " DAY) ";

    SQL_getColors += " AND category.name = '"+categoryName+"'";

    SQL_getColors += " ) as p group by p.color";

    List<Map<String, Object>> colorList = null;
    try {
        colorList = getJdbcTemplate().queryForList(SQL_getColors);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return colorList;
}
```

Here's the controller which uses this function:

```
public List<Map<String, Object>> getColorList(String days, String categoryName) {
    StatusDAO statusDao_i = (StatusDAO)this.context.getBean("statusDAO");
    List<Map<String, Object>> colorList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        colorList = statusDao_i.listColorsOverDays(days, categoryName);
    } catch (BadSqlGrammarException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return colorList;

}
```

A status list which contains the colors:

```
public List<Status> getStatusList(Status status) {
    StatusDAO statusDao_i = (StatusDAO)this.context.getBean("statusDAO");
    status.setCategoryId(this.categoryService_i.getCategoryId(status.getCategoryName()));

    Timestamp fromTime = Timestamp.valueOf(status.getFromTime());
    Timestamp toTime = Timestamp.valueOf(status.getToTime());
    List<Status> statusList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        statusList = statusDao_i.getStatusesByTime(status, fromTime, toTime);
        status.setCategoryId(this.categoryService_i.getCategoryId(status.getCategoryName()));
    } catch (BadSqlGrammarException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return statusList;
}
```

Comment: I'd like to break down that a bit for clarity: You know how to send emails and how to code that, right? You know how to query the database for status changes, correct? If so then I don't quite get your problem, if not then you might want to state the actual problem more clearly.

Comment: Oh and btw, things like `" ... INTERVAL " + days + " DAY "`, i.e. just appending the parameter value to the query string is prone to SQL injection so you either want to change that to use precompiled statements or be _very_ careful on where and how `listColorsOverDays()` is called.

Comment: What is the concrete problem you need help with?

Comment: No, I don't know how to query the database for status changes, is that possible? That would be great if that is possible. As I mentioned I don't know the part where the java speaks with the DB, that's why I just copy+pasted the methods from the project and wondered if those can be used